# MySQL MATCH AGAINST - dealing with a single quote

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I am just learning about `MATCH .. AGAINST` in MySQL and intent to use it now that I understand the basics of it.  I have run across some of our legacy code and want to get some feedback.  Here it is:

```
foreach( $validSearchWords as $word ) { //this is a cleaned array of the user query phrase
    $mycount++;

    // uses a special character
    if (strpos($word,"'")) {
        $wordCriteria['keyword'] .= '"'.$word.'"'; //really? can't be right!
        // if only one search term
    } elseif ($vcount == $mycount) {
        $wordCriteria['keyword'] .= $word.'*';
        // if term is second or higher
    } else {
        $wordCriteria['keyword'] .= $word.'* ';
    }
}
```

I understand what is being attempted here BUT I suspect that first logic block is incorrect.

`Texas State University` would become: `Texas* State* University*`
**BUT**
`John O'Malley High School` would become `John* "O'Malley"High* School*

That can't be right, I think the programmer just got their operations incorrect, because:

a) there is no space after O'Malley

b) they're losing the wild card on a word just because it has a single quote which seems strange.  If they really intend the wild card then it should be like this, right?

```
John* O'Malley* High* School*
```

**UPDATE**
The more concise question is, "How do you represent words with single quotes like O'Malley with a wildcard?

This:

```
SET @keyword='O\'malley*';
SELECT * FROM all_schools WHERE match (school_name) against (@keyword IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

gives me results with only `Malley`, which I don't want. I want `O'Malley` and `O'Malleygough` if it exists

Comment: I don't see a SQL query anywhere in either you question or code snippet.

Comment: agreed, and I added one to clarify.  The real question is, "How do you do a boolean mode search for `O'Malley*`  that does NOT match just Malley, but does match O'Malley and O'Malleygough ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to escape the single quote using `''` or `\'`.

```
foreach( $validSearchWords as $word ) { //this is a cleaned array of the user query phrase
    $mycount++;

    $word = str_replace('\'', '\'\'', $word);
    // if only one search term
    if ($vcount == $mycount) {
        $wordCriteria['keyword'] .= $word.'*';
        // if term is second or higher
    } else {
        $wordCriteria['keyword'] .= $word.'* ';
    }
}
```

A better solution would be to use [mysqli::escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [PDO::quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)